# Problem with creating Java project in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, generator

I've downloaded IntelliJ but for some reason, I cant find a generator for java. I've shown it too a few friends but they cant see whats wrong either, because they all have the java generator.

[image: A picture of what my intelliJ screen looks like]

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

The option to create a plain Java project is right there in your screenshot: Choose `New Project`, then choose `Java` as the `language`. Specify your choice of build tool; if new to Java then I suggest `Maven`, but for a bigger and complicated project use `Gradle`.

## Enhanced *New Project* wizard

You are seeing the new enhanced *New Project* wizard introduced in IntelliJ 2022.1.

Personally, I approve. I like the compact view showing the mix of language, build, and JDK options.

See [*What’s New in IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1*](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/). To quote:

> We reworked the New Project wizard interface to streamline creating new projects. You can quickly launch an empty project; use the pre-configured options for Java, Kotlin, Groovy, and JavaScript; or use generators if you have projects that are more complex.

[image]

Or click any of those specialized generators listed beneath the heading *Generators*. For example, *Maven Archetype* where you choose from a list of commonly used archetypes, or *JavaFX* to make  project loaded with a fully functioning GUI app.

To specify an initial Java package, specify a Maven *GroupId* as seen in this screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Well when I see someone like code with mosh or some others using IntelliJ they start with a prompt that contains a package and a class but not anymore?

Comment: It still stinks, it isn't able to create a jar file out of the box with the jar command, it doesn't see manifest file and overwrites it with its own.  Something so basic as Java project should just work out of the box.  Eclipse used to do so easily.

Comment: @Blund.n I do not understand your Comment. (a) What is "mosh"? (b) In the *New Project* dialog, click the disclosure triangle labeled *Advanced Settings* to specify a Maven *GroupId* which also acts as the initial package in your new project. I added a second screenshot to show this explicitly.

Comment: @JPM What stinks exactly? Run the Maven command *install* to generate a JAR file.

Answer (score 1):

Even tho there doesn't appear a Generator for Java you can still create a Java project, in the picture that you showed us it says Language and there is a Java option, they even give you the option to work with IntelliJ, Maven or Gradle. This type of project is going to be the same as a project generated with a Java generator. Here it is the documentation of how to create a new IntelliJ project, and it looks the same as yours https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/new-project-wizard.html#new-project-no-frameworks

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the sample code, from the previous java version, when creating a new Java project you just need to press the "Add sample code" box ^^^.